# Can unofficial Blender addons be included in a project as a text block and automatically register on load?

Tags: scripting, add-on

I am a keen user of Bassam's typewriter.py addon. It's not part of the official distribution, so I thought I could make my .blend projects more portable by including it as a text block.

I always need to run the block even though I checked the register checkbox.
Are there any more requirements to having the .py extension that I need to do before the script will run on load?

- http://www.blendernation.com/2013/01/25/typewriter-blender-addon/

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes, if the addon is a single file (rather then a python package containing an `__init__.py` file).

At the end of the script, remove these two lines:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

And add this line:

```
register()
```

In Python `__name__` refers to the module name, which in this case is the name of the textblock (without `.py`, however if you run the script directly `__name__` will be `"__main__"`).

Removing this check before calling the register() function will run no matter how its executed.

---

*Note, if you do this - The script won't be listed in the preferences as an addon, this wont cause problems, but a user has no way to disable besides restarting blender.*